# How to Show Testimonial List By Category in Testimonial Slider Plugin

Tags: wordpress, list, slider, shortcode

I have a wordpress testimonial page and i am using this '[testimonialList set="1"]'
Shortcode to show testimonial list on my page. But i want to show specific category testimonial list on my page.
The above shortcode shows all the testimonials.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/testimonial-slider/

Comment: try to read the document about the plugin

Comment: i have read about the plugin it gives a shortcode to show testimonialslider from a specific category but not testimonial lists from a specific category.

Comment: check it here http://guides.slidervilla.com/testimonial-slider/shortcodes/category-specific-testimonials/

Comment: it shows slider from a specific category not a list from a specific category. i do not want slider here.

Comment: oops it is `Testimonial Slider` plugin so showing the testimonials as slider

Comment: Yes Its Testimonial Slider, Actually i need both slider on home page and and testimonial list on testimonial page. thats why i was asking if anyone can help me. i dont want to use two different plugin for this.

Comment: ok breakup the code of testimonials without slider and paste it on the your theme `functions.php` and call the function where you want